# java.lang.AssertionError: expected: org.json.JSONObject<{"feedback":[]}> but was: org.json.JSONObject<{"feedback":[]}>

Tags: java, json, maven, spring-boot, junit

I wrote a test of a method which have one condition. As per condition it should be empty and it is returning empty response but there is assertion error.

```
@Test 
public void testExtractData_feedbackRecords_withBadWords() throws Exception {
    //given
    JSONArray tags = new JSONArray();
    tags.put("ios_pre");
    tags.put("andr_pre");
    tags.put("web_pre");

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("group_id", "28430278");
    jsonObject.put("created_at", "2019-04-05T00:00:00Z");
    jsonObject.put("updated_dt", "");
    jsonObject.put("status", "status-test");
    jsonObject.put("ticket_id", "1");
    jsonObject.put("id", "1");
    jsonObject.put("description", "----- Sender Info ----- Body:body1 adult platform=platform1");

    JSONArray feedbackRecords = new JSONArray();
    feedbackRecords.put(jsonObject);

    JSONArray empty = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject expected = new JSONObject();
    expected.put("feedback", empty);

    ZendeskExtractor mockZendeskExtractor = PowerMockito.mock(ZendeskExtractor.class);
    PowerMockito.doReturn(feedbackRecords)
            .when(mockZendeskExtractor, "extractFeedback", Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(String.class));
    when(mockZendeskExtractor.extractData("2019-04-05T00:00:00Z", DateTime.parse("2019-04-25T00:00:00Z")))
            .thenCallRealMethod();

    //when
    JSONObject actualData =
    mockZendeskExtractor.extractData("2019-04-05T00:00:00Z", DateTime.parse("2019-04-25T00:00:00Z"));

    //then
    assertEquals(expected, actualData);
}
```

Getting following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: org.json.JSONObject<{"feedback":[]}> but was: org.json.JSONObject<{"feedback":[]}>
```

Comment: JEE's `JSONObject` is an `interface`, not a `class` and cannot be instantiated with `JSONObject expected=new JSONObject();`. Which implementation of `JSONObject` are you using?

Comment: `org.json.JSONObject ` is a class not interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your assertion like:

```
assertEquals(expected.toString(), expected2.toString());
```

It should pass test now. For further details please [click here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert)

Comment: This works but can you explain me why this happen as we are comparing identical objects.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. You are relying on the structure of the strings. Also your "source" is just a site that collects random code snippets from the internet. -1